# Why does use of 'if' not work in C# single expression lambda methods and Expression-bodied methods?

Tags: c#, lambda, compilation

I watched Mads video on some of the new C# 6.0 features.
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2015-Enterprise-Videos/Whats-New-in-CSharp-6#time=0s

At about 2:40, he talks about methods that have only a single expression can be condensed using the lambda notation like this

```
void DoSomething() => "".Count();
```

This is based off of single expression lamdba's like this:

```
Action doSomething = () => "".Count();
```

Then I tried to toss a quick `if` in before, and the C# 6.0 shorthand method and I get the good old "Invalid token 'if' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" message.
ex:

```
void DoSomething() => if(true) "".Count(); //Problem!
```

Then I wondered if this was ever supported in C# 5.0 with single expression lamdba's.... Of course, it never was, and when I do this, I get the same error:

```
Action doSomething = () => if(true) "".Count(); //Also problem!
```

So, my only conclusion is that `if(true) executeExpression();` doesn't count as being a "single expression body" and/or the C# specification has limitations on what qualifies as a single expression body to limit the complexity of magic that the compiler has to do to implement this.

I would have thought `if`, `for`, `foreach`, `try`, `using`, etc. would work, but I understand the complexity of having to deal with nested blocks of these.

Comment: This is related to the grammar, `if` is a statement and `?:` is the equivalent expression. Optimizations happens after the parsing step.

Comment: `?:` basically returns an expression inline, right? where as `if` just conditionally executes code w/o having to return an expression.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the two most important words in Mephy's comment are *statement* and *expression*. The difference is important.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, I think I see where you're going... so `if(true)` is a separate statement then the `executeSomething()` that follows it? In which case the constraint on the lambda syntax is "single-statement" and not "single-expression". (I guess almost everything could be compiled down into a single expression)

Comment: @matrixugly no, `'if' '(' <condition> ')' <statement> ('else' <statement>)?` is a statement. `if(true)` is just a syntax chunk without meaning to the compiler.

Comment: Not really... the constraint is *single expression*, it just so happens that `executeSomething()` is... an *expression statement*. Statements aren't allowed, expressions are. Also note that lambdas can use the `=> { ... }` syntax, whereas you can't use that with expression-bodied members.

Comment: You've already correctly determined that _"`if(true) executeExpression();` doesn't count as being a "single expression body""_. Do you have an actual _question_ here? I don't understand what it is you're trying to ask here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, Thanks for your feedback. Instead of asking "y this no working?", I was just throwing out some guesses for research value. Lucas' comment above about statements vs. expressions was helpful in seeing *why* the guess was correct. And I feel the question is pretty explicit. "why does 'if' not work in the shorthand lambda syntax?" Perhaps you missed the title? Or there's a better way to word it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right there in the name: "expression-bodied methods". `if` is not an expression, it's a *statement*, which is why using it in an expression-bodied method is not valid.

Another case where this distinction matters is `throw`. `throw` is also a statement, which means you currently can't use it in an expression-bodied method:

```
void M() => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

For this reason, [`throw` is being considered to be made into an expression in C# 7](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5143).

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Should remember back to compiler theory... "An expression is something that returns in place of itself, a value." I see that an "if" statement does not return in place of itself a value.